# D equivalent to XMLHttpRequest functions

Tags: d, httprequest

I am looking for an example code to make an http request in D, something how the XMLHttpRequest of jscript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some people have created wrappers for libcurl, which you can use to make http requests.

Try this one. https://github.com/gmfawcett/d-play-libcurl/blob/master/fawcett/curl.d

Comment: @The Mask, thank you, if you're happy could you mark the question as answered.

Comment: When I try to build with this, I get a build error:  `Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D4curl12__ModuleInfoZ`.  I simply copied `curl.d` into `phobos\std\net\` and then added the line `import std.net.curl;` at the top of my `main.d` file.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any D library that has that sort of functionality, though someone may have written one. There certainly isn't any HTTP anything in the standard library yet. It may very well get in there at some point, but D's standard library - Phobos - is still fairly young. Something that domain-specific certainly isn't in there yet.

So, either you'll need to be able to find a library that someone has already written, or you're going to need to write it yourself. But there is no standard way to do it in D yet.

Answer (score 1):

std.net.curl from standard library
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html

(as I understand situation changed since 2011)